# PS1 for Bash + Korn

Tags: bash, ksh, colors, aix, prompt

I am trying to set a prompt for bash shell which is working however this particular system also uses Korn quite a bit.

```
echo ~/.profile -> export PS1="\[\033[38;5;10m\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[\]"
```

In Bash:

```
[root@mysystem ~]$ (in green)
```

In Korn:

```
[033[38;5;10m][u@h W]$ [] (default color)
```

I need to set it correctly for both shells.

Comment: What implementation / version of the Korn shell?

Comment: See also [Using echo -e in PS1 causes line break issues in shell](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/367487)

Comment: trying to find the version... its an AIX 6.1 system in the meantime

Comment: I've ended up running strings on the binary, or using control-v, to get the ksh version on AIX.

Comment: Is is possible to do an If shell = bash, do this PS1, else do this PS1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments it sounds like you'd just like to check whether you're running `bash`, and in that case set the `PS1` value for `bash`, and otherwise set it for `ksh`.

This is easy:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # set PS1 for bash
else
    # set PS1 for ksh (or non-bash in general)
fi
```

`[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]` will be true if `$BASH_VERSION` is non-empty, which it will be if the current shell is `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

[Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371503/117549) is good, but just in case someone decides to `export BASH_VERSION` before invoking ksh (thus fooling the test), you could instead test the value of `$0`:

```
case "$0" in
  (*ksh)  PS1="ksh version"     ;;
  (*bash) PS1="bash version"    ;;
  (*)     PS1="default version" ;;
esac
```

This test is not infallible; if you `ln -s /bin/bash /tmp/bashksh`, then invoke `/tmp/bashksh`, the above code will falsely indicate that you are running ksh.